# I Can't recover query string parameter on my custom route - MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

In my application I have the follow route, just before default route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "SubUser",
    url: "{subUser}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { subUser = "0", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    constraints: new RouteValueDictionary { { "subUser", "[0-9]{11,14}" } }
);
```

And I have a `CustomFilter` registered on `app_start/filterconfig.cs` who will try to recover the `subUser` on every request, if it exists, and will persist it to the next response.

But I can't recover it in my `CustomFilter`, on debugger I can see another parameters, but not him.
Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how u trying to recover this parameter? Try to use routeValues. Works for me.

```
public class LocalizationFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        string culture = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["culture"].ToString();
        string subUser = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["subUser"].ToString();       
    }
}
```